# Bootstrap typeahead - Subsections (headers)

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm working with the "typeahead" plugin from Bootstrap.

I load the data with ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/library/autocomplete",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#autocomplete').typeahead({source: data})
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log( "Data is: " + data);
            },
            onComplete: function(){

            }
        });
```

The autocompleteAction:

```
public function autocompleteAction()
{
    // disable view and layout
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    $values = array();

    $usernames = UserQuery::create()->find();
    $usernames = $usernames->toArray();

    $organizations = OrganizationQuery::create()->find();
    $organizations = $organizations->toArray();

    foreach($organizations as $organization){
        array_push($values, $organization["Name"]);
    }
    foreach($usernames as $username){
        array_push($values, $username["Username"]);
    }

    echo $this->_helper->json($values);
    exit;
}
```

As you can see I load usernames AND organizations from the database so you can add both of them.

Now when I type in the textbox I see hints from organizations and usernames. Is there a way to add a title and show the organizations under "Organization Title" and usernames under "Usernames Title".

An image for clarifcation:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Example can be found here : http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Check example "NBA and NHL Teams" on the page!

Comment: Hi, It's good answer. But when I use this example my code send two requests. It is possible to do it, but send only one request ?